# TypeScript: How do I get get rid of TS2322 error when assigning object values in a loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

> **TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"top" |
> "center" | undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> '"top" | "center" | undefined'.**

Code:

```js
export type AlertType = 'success' | 'exclamatory' | 'danger' | 'warning' | 'info';

interface RenderProps {
  title?: string;
  content?: string;
  type?: AlertType | string;
}

const defaultProps: RenderProps = {
  title: '',
  content: '',
  type: 'success',
}

const getProps = ( props: RenderProps ): RenderProps => {
  const _props: RenderProps = {};
  for ( let prop in defaultProps ) {
    const _prop = prop as keyof RenderProps;
    _props[ _prop ] = typeof props[_prop] !== 'undefined' ? props[_prop] : defaultProps[_prop];
  }
  return _props;
}
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, your code compiles without error with TypeScript 5.1.3.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why it's showing in the editor

Comment: Post your `tsconfig.json` and the exact version of `tsc` that your build-system, and your editor, are using. Your editor _may_ be using a different version of `tsc` compared to your build script.

Comment: Here's the tsconfig: https://pastebin.com/E6fycf8v
TypeScript version: 5.1.6

Comment: Can you share error on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?# ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; it works perfectly there but not in the editor which feels strange, I've tried on both VSCode & PHPStorm